# How to track and update a great many values efficiently?

Tags: python, oop, simulation

I'm making a program that simulates governments and families in the medieval ages. People (represented by objects of the class `Actor`) are born, grow old, have kids, and die.

This means I need to track quite a few objects, and figure out some to e.g. call `update_age()` for every tracked person every year/month/week.

This brings up several problems. I need to find some way to iterate over the set of all tracked `Actor`s. I also need to be able to dynamically add to that set, to account for births.

My first idea was to make an object `Timekeeper` with a method that calls `update_age()` for every object in the set of tracked objects. Then, in the main program loop, I would call the Timekeeper's method. However, this makes `Timekeeper` a singleton, a concept which is not always a good idea. Since I am only a novice programmer, I'd like to learn good design patterns now, rather than learn wrong.

It still leaves me with the problem of how to get a set/list/dictionary of all the tracked people to update.

Comment: How about the publisher-subscriber model?

Comment: Are the only events you are interested in the 3: being born, having kids, dying?

Comment: @Schollii No, there are several other types of events (declarations of war, etc); I just listed those as examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a simulation, it is certainly reasonable design to have a single "simulation engine", with various components. As long as you don't implement these as application-wide singletons, you will be fine. This is actually a great example of what the advice to avoid singletons is actually all about! Not having these as singletons will allow, for example, running several simulations at once within the same process.

One of the common designs for a system such as yours is an event-based design. With such a design, you'll have a single event manager component for the simulation. It will support registering functions to be called given certain conditions, e.g. a given amount of simulation time has passed. You can then register your `update_age()` events to be fired off at intervals for each of the `Actor`s in your simulation.

If you go this route, remember that you will need to be able to remove registered event handlers for `Actor`s that are no longer relevant, e.g. if they die in the simulation. This can be done by creating a unique ID for each registered event, which can be used to remove it later.

Comment: Are you suggesting I make a top-level function to handle each and every object (using some sort of function factory), so `obj_0671` would be handled by `handler_0671()`, or am I misreading your answer?

Comment: No, I am suggesting that your simulation includes a single event manager object, with e.g. a method `call_every_month()`, so you could use e.g. `event_mgr.call_every_month(obj_0671.update_age)`. The event manager could have a list of such event handlers to call, sorted by time to be activated, and would pop handlers from the list in every iteration. Handlers which should be called repeatedly would be re-inserted into the list with the next time they should be called. For more information and details, read about [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution that avoids a singleton is a producer/consumer model with a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).  You have a queue with a producer that pushes to the queue and a consumer that pops from the queue.  The producer runs in a loop and can add functions to the queue which should be run on the set of actors within a given simulation.  Then the consumer pops the functions off the queue and applies them to the list of actors (in sequence).

So for example you might push a function that takes a list (actors) and updates everyone's age by 1.  Or a function that finds every adult female actor and randomly selects 10% of them to have children, who are subsequently appended to the list.

It's not the first implementation that springs to mind but since I've already seen event loop and pub/sub mentioned I figured I would provide a different alternative.